# Place details in google api javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using the API to display the location details of a place. However I am not able to display the map also. When I tried to debug the java script I am getting reference error in

```
 service.getDetails()
```

I want to show the location details in an info window in a on click event of the marker. Can any one help me out in this.Here is my code

```
function initialize() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316),
zoom: 15
});

var request = {
reference: 'CnRkAAAAGnBVNFDeQoOQHzgdOpOqJNV7K9-c5IQrWFUYD9TNhUmz5-  aHhfqyKH0zmAcUlkqVCrpaKcV8ZjGQKzB6GXxtzUYcP-muHafGsmW-1CwjTPBCmK43AZpAwW0FRtQDQADj3H2bzwwHVIXlQAiccm7r4xIQmjt_Oqm2FejWpBxLWs3L_RoUbharABi5FMnKnzmRL2TGju6UA4k'
};

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
 });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly load this library in your request;

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=yourApiKey

Comment: I am loading that library like this                                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

Answer (score 0):

The place reference is only valid within a session.  You can't save the string and use it again.

```
var request =  {
      reference: place.reference
};
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
    service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var contentStr = '<h5>'+place.name+'</h5><p>'+place.formatted_address;
        if (!!place.formatted_phone_number) contentStr += '<br>'+place.formatted_phone_number;
        if (!!place.website) contentStr += '<br><a target="_blank" href="'+place.website+'">'+place.website+'</a>';
        contentStr += '<br>'+place.types+'</p>';
        infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
      } else { 
        var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status="+status+"</h5>";
        infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
      }
    });
```

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-searchboxC.html?q=airport)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But am not able to get the reference of that place dynamically using the place.reference now.If I use some static value like "'CnRkAAAAGnBVNFDeQoOQHzgdOpOqJNV7K9-c5IQrWFUYD9TNhUmz5-aHhfqyKH0zmAcUlkqVCrpaKcV8ZjGQKzB6GXxtzUYcP-muHafGsmW-1CwjTPBCmK43AZpAwW0FRtQDQADj3H2bzwwHVIXlQAiccm7r4xIQmjt_Oqm2FejWpBxLWs3L_RoUbharABi5FMnKnzmRL2TGju6UA4k'
  }; " this its working.